# 'a' link without href in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for a login page, I've seen people use the  tag without the 'href' in bootstrap but it's not working for me, any ideas?

I'm just trying a simple alert atm before finishing, I will have the link switch between login and sign-up pages when I can get this working. At the moment it just appears as plain text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Secret Diary</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <section id="login">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
            <h1>Secret Diary</h1>
            <h2>Store you thoughts</h2>
            <div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
            <form method="post" id="signupForm">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value="1"> Stay Logged In
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="signUp" value="1">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" value="Sign Up!">
              <p><a id="showLogInForm">Log In</a></p>
            </form>

            <form method="post" id="loginForm">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value="1"> Stay Logged In
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="signUp" value="0">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" value="Log in!">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#showLogInForm").click(function(){
      alert("hi!");
    });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `href="#"` for a tags that shouldn't go anywhere

Comment: It's a good idea to wrap all jQuery code in $('document').ready(function(){ `your code goes here` }) your on click handler is probably attaching to something that doesn't exist yet, so you need to tell jquery to wait until the document is ready. also I don't know if it is needed but I have always seen hrefs on anchors but if the href is unused it's usually `href=#`

Comment: Agree with Charlie or pass in the event to the handler and perform `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak his script is at the bottom of his page so a document ready is unnecessary

Comment: ^ or use `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Comment: @Taplar lol show's how well I know jQuery. That makes sense though, in that case yes I would call preventDefault as you mentioned

Comment: You probably need need a `href` attribute, most css is setup to display a tags without href as plain text.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working for me"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just use the a tag without href like this:
`<a id="showLogInForm">Log In</a>`
please refer to the code below for details:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Secret Diary</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <section id="login">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
            <h1>Secret Diary</h1>
            <h2>Store you thoughts</h2>
            <div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
            <form method="post" id="signupForm">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value="1"> Stay Logged In
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="signUp" value="1">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" value="Sign Up!">
              <p><a id="showLogInForm">Log In</a></p>
            </form>

            <form method="post" id="loginForm">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value="1"> Stay Logged In
                </label>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="signUp" value="0">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4" value="Log in!">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


    

    <script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#showLogInForm").click(function(){ alert("hi!"); });
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just tried using;
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showLogInForm">Log In</a>

But it still doesn't call this alert
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#showLogInForm").click(function(){
      alert("hi!");
    });
    </script>

Comment: check the answer it is working now, i think there is some problem with the external files you are linking in your code include them in head and check if the path is correct

Comment: There was a file linked incorrectly but your code worked, thanks

Comment: Please provide some information. Do not reply with code only.

Comment: This answer is not really useful as it's difficult to identify what's been changed. Provide description of change, please.

Comment: Down voted for lack of explanation so it's not useful without having to go line by line to see what changed.

Comment: This is the answer that the questioner was looking for. Further validating this answer is the fact that I just dug into the USPS "Schedule a Pickup" web page code and found that it uses code nearly identical code for the buttons on its page.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="showLogInForm">Log In</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `<button>` with some classes

```
<button class="btn btn-link p-0">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need need a `href` attribute, most browsers' default styling is setup to display `a` tags without href as plain text.

```html
<a>some link</a>
<br />
<a href="#">some other link</a>
```

Comment: Breaks vue router

Comment: Breaks angular router too !

Comment: Yes, this (and similar methods like `javascript:void(0)`) will break the routers of pretty much every framework, as they all have their own special ways to handle links and routing. But, all of those either already have button/text styled as links or links that doesn't route to anywhere, or can be easily added if they are missing. If you need something like that for react/vue/angular etc. you should be able to easily find the answer you're looking for with a google search.